# Adding smallrye mutiny dependency in JBoss EAP 7.3

Tags: reactive-programming, jboss-eap-7, microprofile, smallrye-reactive-messaging, smallrye

I have a microprofile application using Smallrye Mutiny, which I need to deploy on JBoss EAP 7.3. I have applied JBoss EAP XP patch to enable microprofile features. I have also added mutiny jar as a module in EAP.
Below are the module file contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" 
name="io.smallrye.reactive.mutiny">
   <resources>
      <resource-root path="mutiny-0.9.0.jar" />
   </resources>
   <dependencies>
      <module name="org.reactivestreams" />
   </dependencies>
</module>
```

And the module.xml for reactivestreams is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.reactivestreams">
   <resources>
      <resource-root path="reactive-streams-1.0.3.jar" />
   </resources>
</module>
```

However in my application I'm getting the below Exception
Failed to define class io.smallrye.mutiny.Multi in Module "deployment.SampleReactive.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link io/smallrye/mutiny/Multi (Module "deployment.SampleReactive.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Publisher

How can I configure JBoss EAP to work with reactive applications built using Microprofile? Any help is appreciated.

**Edit**: I have managed to get the app working on EAP 7.3. But now I am facing a different issue.
App has REST Apis which emit Uni and Multi. The REST API produces Json. But when I run this program in EAP, I see and object as the response instead of a JSON.
It seems that EAP is not able to convert Uni and Multi to JSON.

Is there any library that I need to add for this to work?